# Errors when opening Power Shell or VSC

Tags: windows, parsing

When I open Windows PowerShell or VSC it prints this message:

Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:768

- ... es\Git\cmd;"C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Use ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

Unexpected token 'C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Shawn\anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 char:9

- ```
      Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

How do I remedy this so that I can be sure that my system will run things correctly.